# Isotope masonry hover state not working

Tags: php, hover, z-index, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have used Isotope in my new site and the problem I am facing is when I hover the individual item a div which is bigger in size providing additional description should be displayed but it is getting hidden or cut off by the other divs. What I want to achieve is similiar to the www.ted.com site.

This is the html part of my grid which pulls the individual abstract from the database

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">

    <?php

    $sql="SELECT * FROM abstracts where year='2012' AND status='publish' order by date_added desc LIMIT 0, 15";

    $sql_query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query))

    {

    ?>
            <a href="http://www.painlink.org/staging/login.php"> 

            <div class="category <?php echo $specialities;?>" data-symbol="Hg" data-category="basicscience">
            <div class="Border">
                <img src="cropper.php?src=admin/images/journals/<?php echo $row['journal_image'];?>&h=180&w=120&zc=1">
                **<span><div id="filterLink_text"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div></span>**
            </div>
            </div></a>

        <?php 
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

I have also changed the following in the css so that it is higher than the isotope-item

```
.isotope-item:hover { 
    z-index: 10; 
}
```

The bolded span which is hidden has to be displayed upon hovering.

My site url is www.painlink.org/staging

Can you please help me out with this.

Cheers,
Neethi

Comment: Your are just nesting your Isotope elements wrongly. If you want to show content over an image on hover you should use that logic: Create a div (Isotope element) and inside that div, you nest two more divs; one with your image, video, whatever, and one with your content, text, etc. that shall appear on hover. In your CSS, you hide that content with display: none. Then, you can simply show() or animate() the content to be shown on top of your image. If your content is larger than the image, Isotope will grow the element and relayout automatically. Example http://adammunns.com/grid-portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a similar thing and I used the script from the site http://www.maxmedia.com. It's not that easy to accomplish. You can try to dissassmble the javascript from maxmedia. They used compressed javascript so you need a good editor. There is also the problem when you mouse out from a tile and mouse over another tile quickly again and again it seems that the mouse event sometimes didn't work. Then you must register the events in a controller. About the hidden span I don't see a problem here but I think you need to solve it using animate. You must unhide the span and scroll the image and the span simultanously so that the span is fully visible and the image is hidden when you don't want to grow the tile.